# Issue with armature mirroring on bones

Tags: armature, mirror

I have an issue with my armature attached to my character.  Basically when I put bones in one hand it keeps getting attached to my other hand as well, even if I delete the bones and start over.  What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Good question, I'm just editing it slightly to make it a bit clearer. Hope you don't mind. (:

Comment: And that looks like a mirroring issue. Is mirroring turned on somewhere, like with a mirror modifier?

Comment: hey, I have mirror turned on with the body but this issue does not pop up with any other bone.

Comment: Weird, I would expect it to apply to all of the bones. I believe there is an option to mirror bones, but only if they have a specific naming scheme (_Bone_\_L, _Bone_\_R). Maybe that is doing something?

Comment: Hey, you actually helped me figure it out.  I have to do the flip name function when I mirror the bones.  Thank you.